# Best practices before migrating SharePoint 2013 content

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, backup, restore

We are planning to backup/restore whole SharePoint 2013 Site Collections from Quality to Production. Our team will delete all the content after restoration.

Can anybody tell the best practices to do so, and caution to take before/after restoration?

1 of the case I can make out is, restoration and before deleting list items, what about Workflow - Will they run, if yes, where they will update data or send email etc. and how to restrict such updates/email.

Answer (score 0):

Few things that comes to my mind:

1. **Managed metadata** : If you have any MMS fields make sure that all MMS terms are migrated to the new system with the same Guid.
2. **Search Result sources** defined at site collection and site level will not get migrated. You will have to recreate this.
3. **Custom Managed properties** created in source and other changes to managed properties in Search schema will have to be redone again.

Comment: Unnie, Is it possible to migrate Manually created Managed Properties via Poweshell or Import/Export (in one shot)?

Comment: @Chintan.Desai yes you can automate all the above things using powershell scripts and is the best way to do it, if you have a lot of properties